# Python ElementTree - iterate through child nodes and text in order

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I am using python the third and the ElementTree API. I have some xml of the form:

```
<root>
  <item>Over the <ref id="river" /> and through the <ref id="woods" />.</item>
  <item>To Grandmother's <ref id="house" /> we go.</item>
</root>
```

I want to be able to iterate through the text and child nodes for a given item in order. So, for the first item, the list I want printed line by line would be:

```
Over the 
<Element 'ref' at 0x######>
 and through the 
<Element 'ref' at 0x######>
.
```

But I can't figure out how to do this with ElementTree. I can get the text in order via `itertext()` and the child elements in order in several ways, but not them interleaved together in order. I was hoping I could use an XPath expression like `./@text|./ref`, but ElementTree's subset of XPath doesn't seem to support attribute selection. If I could even just get the original raw xml contents of each item node, I could parse it out myself if necessary.

Comment: how should look the final output?

Comment: The output is stated above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml = """<root>
  <item>Over the <ref id="river" /> and through the <ref id="woods" />.</item>
  <item>To Grandmother's <ref id="house" /> we go.</item>
</root>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

for item in root:
    if item.text:
        print(item.text)
    for ref in item:
        print(ref)
        if ref.tail:
            print(ref.tail)
```

`ElementTree`s representation of "mixed content" is based on `.text` and `.tail` attributes. The `.text` of an element represents the text of the element up to the first child element. That child's `.tail` then contains the text of its parent following it. See the [API doc](http://effbot.org/zone/pythondoc-elementtree-ElementTree.htm#elementtree.ElementTree._ElementInterface.tail-attribute).